# Direct two-way streaming between two devices

Tags: xamarin, raspberry-pi, mono, streaming, audio-streaming

I have a set up where a Xamarin app is streaming audio to a Mono app in Raspberry Pi (both devices are using the same Wi-Fi network). At the same time the Raspberry Pi app is streaming another audio to a Xamarin app. What is the easiest way to implement this? I'm particularly concerned about the streaming aspect of this set up (transferring a file would be a little easier).

Answer (score 1):

Why not using websocket, if you assume that each device could be in the same time server and client, you may use [whisper](https://github.com/jeff1evesque/whisper) which :

> contains the required submodules to stream audio from the browser to
>   the server.

Answer (score 1):

The best bets for you would be to implement this functionality using:

- **Wi-Fi Direct** - both devices support Wi-Fi and both can implement Wi-Fi direct peer to peer connection. Xamarin.Android offers [`Android.Net.WiFi.P2p`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/Android.Net.Wifi.P2p/) namespace and on RPI it depends on the OS and programming interface you use, for example Windows 10 IoT has the [`Windows.Devices.WiFiDirect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.wifidirect) namespace that you can use for this.
- **Bluetooth** - if your RPI has BT module, you could establish a connection between Android and RPI via Bluetooth and stream the audio between them this way. Android's namespace for this would be [`Android.Bluetooth`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/Android.Bluetooth/) and Windows 10 IoT for example has [`Windows.Devices.Bluetooth`](http://Windows.Devices.Bluetooth)

These two should offer the most direct connection with as little lag as possible.

Comment: Yearly unclosed answer review - @SiberianGuy , if this heped, please consider accepting the answer as solution so that the question is closed.